# Opportunities to clear Filter Input Field On Button Click using Angular

Tags: angular, mat-table

first of all, iam pretty new to angular and web development in general. Moreover my english sucks but I try my best to express myself clearly.

I got the following scenario:
My tool presents a mat-table to the user that has a textfilter row above it.

The textfilter row is a simple input field that listens for the keyup event which will trigger the following function:

```html
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

This works fine. Now I want to give the user the opportunity to clear the input field by pressing a "Clear" button next to it.I have no idea how i can access the input field and change its value (to "") via typescript.

is it possible to use ViewChild and Element Ref here?

Probably a pretty dumb question but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use keyup event listener on input fields in angular2+? I would take the advantage of two-way-binding. That's really powerful.

Have a look at the sandbox I made for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-breeze-zcrcy

**app.component.html:**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <input
    class="form-check-input"
    type="text"
    name="filterInput"
    [(ngModel)]="inputData"
  />
  <button (click)="clearInput()">CLEAR INPUT</button>

  <div>
    Here is my inputData: {{ inputData }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public inputData: string = "";
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  clearInput() {
    this.inputData = "";
  }
}
```

and don't forget to add the **FormsModule** to your **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> Please keep in mind, ngModel is part of the FormsModule. That is why you have to import the FormsModule to your app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is how i solved it. Is this way clean? I dont feel like it is^^

`#filterField` - added to  in template

`@ViewChild('filterField', {static: false}) filterField: ElementRef;` - added to the component.

Implemented this function for the Clear button click:

```
clearFilter(){
    this.filterField.nativeElement.value = "";
    this.applyFilter("");
  }
```